# What is a more compact way to skip initial list items (or partition list based on an item) in python?

Tags: python, list

I wrote this function to filter a list to show all items after a given item is seen.  Somewhat similar to the builtin string method `str.rpartition(sep)`.  I have a feeling there is a more compact way to do this, perhaps using a list comprehension.  Any ideas?

```
def ignore_until(the_list, match):
    # Ignore all items in the_list prior to match
    found = False
    for index, item in enumerate(the_list):
        if item == match:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        return the_list[index:]
    else:
        return []

my_list = ['red','orange','yellow','green']
assert ignore_until(my_list, 'yellow') == ['yellow','green']
assert ignore_until(my_list, 'blue') == []
```

EDIT:

After seeing the answers for the above question, I realized that 5 of the 6 answers focused on the `index()` builtin method for the list data type.  Actually, I need to use a regular expression, and didn't realize that omitting that from my question would affect people's answers.  Here's the regex code:

```
import re
def ignore_until(the_list, pattern):
    # Ignore all items in the_list prior to the item containing pattern.
    found = False
    for index, item in enumerate(the_list):
        if re.search(string=item, pattern=pattern):
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        return the_list[index:]
    else:
        return []

my_list = ['red','orange','yellow','green']
assert ignore_until(my_list, 'yellow') == ['yellow','green']
assert ignore_until(my_list, 'blue') == []
```

Comment: Someday you will progress from using lists to using iterators and generators also, which don't support index() or slicing. @thg435's improved solution is generally applicable to any Python sequence, iterator, or generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that reproduces what str.partition does (i.e. returns three lists):

```
def partition(lst, item):
    if item in lst:
        n = lst.index(item)
        return lst[:n], [item], lst[n+1:]
    else:
        return lst, [], []

print partition(range(10), 7)
```

and here's a version which works with arbitrary iterables, not necessary lists:

```
def partition(it, item):
    a = [[]]
    for x in it:
        if x == item and len(a) == 1:
            a.append([item])
            a.append([])
        else:
            a[-1].append(x)
    return a

print partition((x for x in range(10)), 7)
```

Improved version:

```
def partition(it, item):
    a = []
    for x in it:
        if x == item:
            return a, [item], list(it)
        a.append(x)
    return a, [], []

print partition((x for x in range(10)), 7)
print partition((x for x in range(10)), 17)
```

Comment: I prefer handling arbitrary iterables, means you can accept a generator or some other sequence that doesn't support sliced access or the index() method. A nice thing about the new str.partition method is that it *always* returns a 3-element list. If item is not in the list, then you will return just a 1-element list. How about init'ing a to `[[],[],[]]`, append to a[0] in your else clause, and if you find item, do `a[1].append(item); a[2].extend(it)`. This will also consume the iterator into a[2], so you'll cleanly exit the for loop (with another StopIteration raised by the iterator).

Comment: Oh, and drop the `and len(a) == 1` from the if condition, you won't need it any more because `a[2].extend(it)` will consume the iterator.

Comment: @Paul: actually, when `item` is found, we can return right away (see edit).

Comment: Test cases: 1) item in middle of list; 2) item at end of list; 3) item at beginning of list; 4) item not in list; 5) item repeated in list; 6) empty list.

Answer (score 5):

It's not much more compact, but how about:

```
def ignore_until(the_list, match):
    try:
        return the_list[the_list.index(match):]
    except ValueError:
        return []

my_list = ['red','orange','yellow','green']

print ignore_until(my_list, 'yellow') # => ['yellow','green']
print ignore_until(my_list, 'blue') # => []
```

Comment: +1 because your code catches only ValueErrors. If a different error occurs (for example, if the_list is None), I like having the error propagate. Some of the other answers would catch it and return [].

Comment: Thanks! The Zen of Python, lines 10 and 11: `Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced.`

Answer (score 3):

why not use the python `yourlist.index(match)` to find the index then apply list slicing. The python `yourlist.index` throws an error if the match is not found so you would need to take care of that.

```
def ignore_until(yourlist, match):
    try:
        return yourlist[yourlist.index(match):]
    except ValueError:
        return []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ignore_until(the_list, match):
    try:
        return my_list[the_list.index(match):]
    except ValueError:
        return []
```

Comment: ok, as I refine this, it just becomes modocache's solution. :)

Comment: your try...except is not a good one. you need to specify the error being caught I reckon

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def ignore_until(the_list, match):
    try:
        return [the_list[the_list.index(object):] for object in l if object == match][0]
    except IndexError:
        return []
```

A little hard to read but it's compact.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally put l in there.  It's supposed to be the_list.

Comment: I realize now that my answer was overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using the list.index() method? It returns the index of the first instance of a specified item (or else it throws an error)

```
def ignore_until(the_list, match):
    if match in the_list:
        index = the_list.index(match)
        return the_list[index:]

    else:
        return []
```

source: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Out of curiousity, is it more pythonic to use the try/catch block most other answers seem to use or the if statement I'm using? I tend to prefer explicitly avoiding exceptions over catching them.

Comment: I'd use your version - it's easier to read. The exception version implies that the reader knows that index() throws ValueError - not something obvious.